# How to change advanced search result page layout?

Tags: magento-1.9

My advanced search result page have 2 page columns but have an empty column on the right side. I wanna change on `local.xml` but I don't know how to. Can you help me?

```
<catalogsearch_advanced_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference> </catalogsearch_advanced_index>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code in local.xml

```
<catalogsearch_advanced_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/empty.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
</catalogsearch_advanced_index>
```

Comment: Nothing has changed. why :(

Comment: i use this page 

<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>

Comment: please add your local.xml code in question